# Firebase RTDB: Can I use wildcarding variables in reference path for offline syncing?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Can I use wildcarding variables in reference path for offline syncing? So I want to cache timeline trips for all days. Code might looks like below. Is it possible?

```
val ref = Firebase.database.getReference("timeline/${day}/trips")
ref.keepSynced(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  A reference object can only refer to a single node.

You might want to consider restructuring your data so that all trips are at the top level so that you can build a reference to all trips for sync.